# Конвертирование base64 строки в массив байт

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

На страничке необходимо загрузить в input type file, а так же вывести эту картинку в img. А далее ajax запросом передать base64 строку на сервер и там перевести её в массив байт.
Вот мой код
View:

```
$('#modalWindow').on('click', '#send', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/LoadImage",
            data: {
                "base64img": $('#autoPicture').attr('src')
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert('Привет');
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error.responseText);
            }
        });
    });

    $('#modalWindow').on('change', '#fileLoader', function () {
        ReadImageUrl(this);
    });

    function ReadImageUrl(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#autoPicture').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
        }
    }
```

Код контроллера:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LoadImage(string base64img)
        {
            byte[] picture = Convert.FromBase64String(base64img);

            return View();
        }
```

Но при попытке конвертации вылетает ошибка с текстом:

> Входные данные не являются действительной строкой Base-64, поскольку содержат символ в кодировке, отличной от Base 64, больше двух символов заполнения или недопустимый символ среди символов заполнения

Хотя если использовать сайт для перевода base64 в image https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter конвертирует нормально.

Если нужен будет пример base64 кода напишите я приведу. Просто он очень большой. Могу привести например начало и конец кода, по моему по ним определяется подходит он или нет. Ну вообщем если нужен будет пример, приведу. Не понимаю почему c# не конвертирует.

Очищенная строка:

```
:/;,////+/++++++/+///////+++++///++/+/++/+/+/+/+/+////+++//////+///+/+/++++///+/+++//+/+//+++/+/+++++/++/++++/++++//+//+++++//+/++++++++++/+/+//+++/++++++//++++/+/++++//+/+++///+++/++++/++/+///+++/++/+++++/+/++++++//////++//+//+///++++++/++++/////+++++///+/+/+///++++//+/+/++////++/++/+/++/+///+/++/++///++/////+/+//+//+++//////++//+/++////+++//+//++++/++/+/+/+/++/++++++++//++/++++++/+/++//++++++/+/+++++++/+///+++++//+/++++/++///++////+/+++/++++++/++/++++/+/+///++//+//++/+/++/+++/+++/+/++///+/++/++//+++/+/+//++/+++/++/++/+//+/+/+///++///++/+///++/+++//+/+//+//++/+/+++/+++++/++/+/++///++/+/++//+/+/++//+//++++/+///+/+//++++/+++////+//++/++/++/+//+/++////+/++//++/+++//++++///++++//+///++/////++///+///++/+/++/++++++/+///+++////++/+++/++///+/+++++//++/++/+/+++++++++++///+//++/++/+++/++/++++////++++/++++/+///++///+//+++/++++/++////+//++++/+/++///++++/++/+++///+++/++/++++/++///+/+/+++///+++/++//+/++/++++++////+/+/+////////+/+//+////++/++++////++++//+/++//+/++/+//+/++//+/++/++//++++/+/+++////////+++/++/+++++/+/++/+//+/++/++++/++///+/++++////+/+/++++++++/++/+//+/+/////+//////+/++++///+/////++++++/++/++/++///+++++++++/++/++/+///+//++++//++////+/++/++//++/+/+/++/+++/++////++///+/++++//+++///+++//+/+/+++++/+//+/++//++///++//+/+++/+////++/+++/////+++/++++//+++//+++//++//+++//+/+//++/++//+/+++//++++///+++/+////+//++/++/+//+//////++/////+++/+//+++++++////++/++//++++//++++///+///+////////////+//+///+///++/+//+++//++++++/+/+/+/++/++++/+/+////+/+/+//+//////+///++///////++//+///++/+++++//////+////++/+//+//+++//+/++//+/+/+/+///++//++/++/+/////++++/++++/++////////+///////+++/++/++//+++////++++/+//++++++++//+++///+++++++++/+/+++//+//++//+/////+///+++//+/+/++/++++//++/+///+///+++//+/+/++///////++++++++++//++++++//+++++//+++++++++++///+////+++/++/+++//+/++++//////////+/////++++++/+/+/++/+++/////++//////+//++/+//+///+++///++///++//+++//+//++//+//+//+///+++/++/////++++///++//++///+++/+///++++//++++/+++++/+///+/++//+//++/+/////+++++/+/++/////+//+/+/++/+/+++++++++///+/+/++/+/+///+++/////+/+/+/+//+++++++/++/++//+////+/////+/++++++/++//++/+++//+/++++/+/+++//+++++/++++//+//++//+///+++/+++++/////++//++++/++++++//+///+/+/++/+++///+//+++/+//++/+/+++//+++/+/+++/++/++/////+++/++/++//++/++++///++++///+++//+/+++++++++++++///+/+//+//+/+///+//+/+++++//++//++++++++//++//+/////+/++//+/+/+/+//++/////+++////+//++++//+/////+++/+++++////+++/+///+/+/+/////+///+/+/+++//+++//+/+/////+++++/+//++/////+/+++++/++//+/+++//++////++++//+/++///+/+/+////++/++++//+/+/////+++/+/+//+++/++++++++/+///++++/+////+++//++/++//+++/+/+///++//++/////+/+//+++++/+///+/+/+/+++/++/+/////+++++/+/+/+//+//++/+/++///++//++++++/+++++//++//+/++/+///+//+++//+++//////+//+//////+/++///++/+//++///+/+//++/+++//////+++/++++///////++///+++///+/////++//++++++++/+++/+/////+///++/+++/+//+++++///+++/+//++/////++++///+/+++//+++///+//////+/+/++///++/+/++///++///////++//++//+++/+/++/++/+++/++///++//+/+/++/+/++/+//+++++/////+/+/////+++/+/++//+/+/+//+/+////++/+///+//+///+/++///+/+/+///+///++++++/////++/++/++/++////+///////+/+/+//+++/+///+//+/+/++/+///+///++/+//////++++/////++/++/++///++////+///++//+/++////++/++/+/+////+++++++++/+/////+//+//+/////+++/+++/++++//++///+//+++++//+/+/++/+/++///++////////+////+/+/+/++////+/+/+//+/+///+++/////+++//+////+/+++/+//+//////+///++++///+/+///++/++/++/+++//++/+++/++//++///++/+////+/////++/++//+////////++++///+++//+/+////////+/+//+++/+++/////++/+++/+/+///++//+++////++/+/+//++++//+/+++/+//+//+///++/+/+///++///++/++//++++++++//+//+///+++//////+++//+////+/+//+///++/+++///++++/+/+/+++/+//+/////+/+/+++/++++++++//++++/////+/////++/+++//+++//+/++++++/+////++//++/++++/+++++//+////+/+/+/+//++++/++++++/+///+/+////+++/+++++/++//+//+/+++//+/////++/+/++++/+//+////+/+++/+++//+/+//++/+//+/+/////+///+/+////++//+///++++////+/++//+///+/+/+//+/+++++//++++++//+/+//+/++/+///+//++//+/+/++///+///++////+++++++//+//++/+///+++//+/+/+/+///++/+//+//+++++//////////++////+++///+++/++++++++++++++++/++/+//++++///+/+///++/+/+/++/++++/////////+/++++/+//++++++///+///+++/++/++/+/+//++///++/+/+//+++++/+/+/++////+++/++/+/++/++//+/+/++///+++//+//++/++/+++++++///+/+++///+///+/+/+++/++/+////+++/////++//+/++/+/+//+//+/+///+++++++//++++/++//+//+/+//++//////+++//+++//+/++//+/++++/++/+++/+/++++/+////////++++++//+/+/+///++++///+/+++/++///+/+///+//+++++//++/+////+/+++////+++++/+++/++////+++///+++////+//+++/+/+/+///////++/++//++++/+/++/////////////+///+//++/++///+/++++/++//+//++/++++/++++++///++//+///+///+/+++/+///++////++/+++++/+++/+/+/++++/++///+//+/+////++++//+/+////+++/+++/++/+++//++++++/////+////+//+//+++//+//////+////+++//+/////+//++/+++/+//+/+++++/+++/+/++/+/++++//+++++++//+///++/++++////++/+++/++++/+/+//+++//+///+/++++/++///++/+/+/+//++++++/++///+/+++/+///+//++/++/++/+/+//++/+//++/+++++/+/++//+/+/////+/+//+++++/+///+/+//++/++/++/++////++++//+/+/+++///+//+/+++++/+++/+/++++++/+/+///++++/++///++///++/++++//++++/////++/++++++/++/+++/+//////+/+++++///////+++//++/+//++/+///+//++/+++++///////+++++/+/++++/+++/+//+//++++//+/+//////++/+/+/+/+//+/+/+//+/++/++/////+//+++/++//+///+++/++//+////++++//+//+//+//+++++++/+/+//++/++//+//+//++++//+++//+/////++++///++//++/+/+++/+++/+++/+//+/++++++++++/+/+++/+//+/++/+++++//+/++/+++/+++//+/////++//++/++/+++////++++/++///+/+//+/////+++//+/+++///+/++/+/++++//+/+/+/+//++++/++//+++///+//+//+////++/+/++///+/+////++++//++/+/+///////++++++/++/++++/+++++/++/++/+++/+//+/+++//+/+///+/+///+++/+/+++/+/+/+/+//+//++/+++++++++/+/+/+++//++/+++++/++++/+/+++//++++/+/+/+/+/+///+//+/+++/+/+/++//++++++//+++++++/+/+///+++++++/++/+++++//////+++/++////////+/++++++/+/////+/++////+/+++/+//+/+/++///+++/+/+++++++/++////++/+/++++++//+///++++/+++++///++/+////+//++/+//++++++////++++/+++/+//+//++/+/++++/++//++++/++++//+++////////+//+/+++++/++++//+/+//+/++++///+//+/++/++////+/++++//+///++//+///++////+///+/++/++///+++++//+++/////+/+/++++++/+/+++///++//+//+///++/+/+++++///+//++//+//+///++/+++//++/++/+/+/+++///+++++//+//+++///+//++++/+/++/+//+/++/++////+/////+++/++++/++++//+////++/+++///+/+//+/+++///+//+++/+//+/++/++/++///+++/+++/++/++/////+/+///+//+++//+++/++++/+//////+//+++////++////+/////////+/+/+++/+++/+++/+/+/++/+/////++++++/+++++++++//+//++////++//////++//+/+//+/+/+/+///++/////////////+///++++++///////++/++///////////+/++/+++/+//+++//++++//+//////++//++//++++/+//////+/++/++++//+/////+/////////++///+////+++////////++//+++////+//+//++/++//////+///////+///++++////++///+++++///+////+/+/++++++//++++/+/+/+/+++////+//++///+/++///++/+/++///+///++////++////////++////+//+++/+/++/+/++/+/+/+++/+//++///////+////+////+++//+/+/////+++//+///+//+/++//+++//+//++/+///+/+/////++/+++/+/////+++////+//++/+/+//+///+/////+//+/++////////////++/////+//////+///+//++//+///////////////+//+//+++/+////////+//+//+++/+//+//++//++///+////+///////+++////+++//+/+//++++++//+/+///+//+///////+/+///+/+++////+///++/+/+//++/++++//+//+////+///+//++/+/+/+/++///+/////+//+/+////+//+///+/++/++/+/+//++/+/+///+++/+//++///+//+++//+++/+//++++/////+++//////////+///++/+///+//++/++/+/+////////////+//+/+++/+/////+/++///////+///++//++///+////+/+/+++//++//++/+///+/+/+//+///+++//////++/////+/+++//+////////////+/////////+++////+//+/+////+//+/+//////////++/+///+////+////////++////+/////+/+++//////+////++/////++/++/////////+/+//+//////+///+//+/++/+/+++///+///////+/+/++/+/+++///+/++/++/+//+/+/++/+/++++////+++/++//+/+//+///+++///++/+///++/+/////+/++++/+++//+/+//++++//+/+/++////+/++++//+/+++//+/++++///++////////+++/++//++++++/////+//+/+//+////+++//+++++++++/++++/+++++/++/++/+++/+/+/+//+++////+/++//+//+++++///++/+/++//+/++/++/+/+//+++///+++++/++/++++/+++/+++++/+++//+/++//+++++/+///+++/++/+++//+++/++/+++/+++++///++/+++/+//++//++//+++/+//+/++++/++/+++++++/+/+++/+/+++/+/+//+///+++///+++++++++/+++/++++/+////+/+++//+//+++/+//+/++++//+/+/+/++/+/+/+/++/++++//+++/+///++/+//+//+/++++//++/+///+/++++///////++/+//+/++++++//++//+/++++/++/+/+++//+//+++//+///+//++//+//+/++++//+///+++++++//+//+/+++++//+++//++++//++/+++/++///+++++///++/+//+++/+/++++++/+/++//++//++/+/++////+++++++/+/+++++//+/+/++++//++++++/+++////++/+//+/+/////+++//++/+////+//++/++/++++/+///+//+++++/++/++///+++/+/++////+//++/+/+/++/++/++++++/////+//+//+//++/+///+++/++//++///++++//++//++++/+++///+/++/+++////+//+//+//+/+++++/++///+/++/+///++++++++/+++/++//////++///+/+++/++/++////++/+++/+/++++//+/++++/++++///+//+/+/+/+/++++/++++//++++/+++/+/+////+++++/++++//+//++++/++//+++//+++++///+++///+///++/+++//+/++/++/+///+/+/+/+/+++/+///+/++/+++++++++//+/+/++++++++//+++///+//+/+/+//++////+++//+/+/+/++++//+/+/+++///++++++/++/+++//+/++///+/+++++++/+////++//++/+++///+++/++///+++//+++/+++/+/++++++/++++++++/+/+//+/+///+/++/+/+/+++//+/+//+/+/+/++++++++++++/++/+/++/+/++++++/+/+++/+++++++/+++/++/+/+//+/+/++/++//////+/+/++/+/+//+/++//+/++++/+++/++//++/+/++/++++/++//++++/+///+++/+++++++/+//++++/++///+//++/++++/+//+//++/+++///++/+/////++/+++++/++++++/++///+/+++/++/+/+/++++/+++++++/+/+/++/+/++++++/++++/+/+++++//+++/+++////++/+++++/+///++///++//++/++++//++/++++++//+++++/++++++++/+/+//+///+++++/+++//+/+++/++/+/+/+/+/+++++/////+/++/+/+++++++++++++++++++//////++/++++/++++++//+/++++++++++/+++/+/++++/++++/+++///+++/+/+/+/+++++//++++//+/++//+/+////+/+/+///+++//////+++/+/+////++++++++/+++///+/+/+++/++++//+++/////////+///+/////+////////++////+/////////+//++//+/+/++////++++////+///++//+///+///+/////+/++//+//+////++++///+/++/++/++/+/+///++/+++/+/++///++//++/+///////+//+/++//////+/+//+/+/++///+++++//+//////++/+/+///+/+++//+/+/////+++//++/++////+++//+++++/++////+//////+++/++++/++++++++/++++////+//+/++////+////+/+///+////+/++/+//+++///+//+///++//++////++//++/+/+//+++/++++/+/++++//+/+//+///++/+/+/+//+//++//++//+/++///+/+/+/+++/////+/+/++///++++/+/+/+///+++++/+//+//+/+/++//++/+/+//+///+//++++++++/+//+//+/+//++++/+/+++//+++++++/+//+/++++/+/+/+/+//+/++++//+//++++++/+///+/+++/++///++///+++//++/+/+/+/++/++++/+/+++/////+/++/+//++++/+/++/+/++++//+///++/+/++////+/+///+++++++/++/++//+//+++/+/+++///++++/++++/+++/++/+/+/+//+/++/++//+//+//+/++/+/+/////+++//++/////+/+//+/+//+/+/+//+//+/+///++//+/+++++/++//+/+++//////++////+//+/++/+++//+///+//+/+++///+//////////+//+///+//+/++////+/+++///+/+//+/++/+++//++///+///++//++///+//+/+//++/+///+///+++//+/++///+/+//+///+//+++++++/++//++/++/+///++++/++/+////+//++/+//////+/+++/++/++//+//+++//+//++//++++++/+/++++/++/++++////+++/+////++///+++++++/+/+++//+++////++/////+//+++/++++//+///+///+++/++/+/+/+/+++/////+++//++///++/+//+///+/+///++/+/++++/+///++///+/////+///////+/+/+++////++//++/+////+++///+/+++//++++/////+///////+/++//++/+/////+/++++/++//++/++//+/+/+//+//+/+++//+/+/+//////+//++/++/+////+///++//+//+/////++/+//+//+//+///++/++///++//++/+///++////++/++/////+/+//////+++//++//+/+/+/+/++++/+/++/+/++//////+//+//++//+/+/+++/++/////+/+/++/++/+/+//+/+++/+/////++/++/+/++//+//+//+++++++/+/+/++//+//+++/+////++//////+/+/////+/+///+/+++////+/++/++/+//+++++/+////+///+////////+/++//+++//////+/+++//////////+/++/++/+++++//+////+/++///+/+++++/+/+/++/+//+///+/++/+/////++///++///+//++/+/+/++/+/++/////+//+/+////+++///++//++///++///+/+/+//++/+///+/+++//+++/++////++/+/+/++++//++//////+++///////+///+///////++++/+////+//+/////++/++++/++++/++//++/+++//+/+/++/+/+++/++/////+/+/+/++///+++/+++++/+/+/++/+///+++/+++/++++//+///+++++/++/+/+//+//++++/+/++///+//+/++/+////+/+///+/++++////////////+//++//++++////++//+//++//+/+++/+/+/+/+/+//++++/+++/+++++//++/++++/+++/+/+//++////+++++//==
```

Comment: Попробуйте убрать из строки все символы base-64 и посмотреть что останется:`var cleanString = Regex.Replace(base64img, "[a-zA-Z0-9]", "")`

Comment: @defaultlocale, сделал, добавляю в вопрос в самом низу.

Comment: @defaultlocale всё добавлено.

Comment: @defaultlocale оказывается нужно вырезать заголовок, `byte[] picture = Convert.FromBase64String(base64img.Substring(23));`

Comment: @defaultlocale но для другой картинки уже такой вариант не подошёл вышла другая ошибка. `Недопустимая длина строки или массива знаков Base-64`

Comment: Не отправляйте данные как строку base64. Отправьте как `blob` или `file`. Это и короче и быстрее и без ошибок непонятных

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, не нашёл такого способа, можете привести пример как можно отправить? И как потом перевести в массив байт для хранения в базе?

Comment: Эти символы `:/;,` до или после удаления заголовка? Попробуйте еще `+` и `/` вычистить из строки: `var cleanString = Regex.Replace(base64img, "[a-zA-Z0-9+/]", "")`

Comment: Отправить можете через `FormData`. Принять - точно не знаю.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko отправить base64 код через FormData? Так уже сделал, пока разницы нет.

Comment: @defaultlocale получилось для первой картинки убрав всё с самого начала и до запятой включая её. Для первой картинки всё получилось. Но я попробовал ещё на 1 картинке, у неё в конце нет ==, и вот она уже не конвертируется если не дописать самому в конец ==.

Comment: Отправлять `blob` или `file` через `FormData`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko привидите пожалуйста пример с кодом оформленном как ответ, не могу понять что вы имеете в виду и как нужно сделать то тчо вы предлагаете.